# Does date->getTimestamp return time 00:00:01 of that date?

Tags: php, date, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am checking to see whether current time is inside a specified range but get odd behavior.

I wonder, maybe when I do $end_date->getTimestamp() I get the timestamp for the first minute of that day?

In that case I would need to add (60*60*24)-1 to the timestamp to get 23:59:59 of that $end_date right?

```
private function check_date_in_range($start_date, $end_date)
{
    //Get current time
    $user_ts = time();

    if ($start_date == null && $end_date == null) {
    //if both are null...           

        return 1;
    }
    elseif ($start_date != null && $end_date != null) {
    // if none is null

        //Convert dates to timestamp for comparison
        $start_ts = $start_date->getTimestamp();
        $end_ts = $end_date->getTimestamp();

        // Check that current date is between start & end otherwise return FALSE.
        return (($user_ts >= $start_ts) && ($user_ts <= $end_ts));
```

Comment: You don't get the timestamp "for the first minute", but the timestamp for whatever your dates are. Since you don't show how they are created we have no idea what that might be. I can only offer that you don't need to convert to timestamps (comparing straight objects is possible) and that doing manual timestamp manipulation is usually going to introduce subtle DST-related bugs.

Comment: Whare are `$start_date` and `$end_date` variables? Can you `var_dump()` them and show us? What must this method return?

Comment: If you're expecting `DateTime` parameters, you should type-hint for them, i.e. `check_Date_in_range(DateTime $start_date = null, DateTime $end_date = null)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test for the inclusive range, you would indeed need to add one more day:

```
$now = new DateTime();

$end_date_next = $end_date;
$end_date_next->modify('+1 day');

return $now >= $start_date && $now < $end_date_next;
```

Or just use string based comparison on just the date portion instead:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');

return $now >= $start_date->format('Y-m-d') && 
    $now <= $end_date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Problem is, we don't know what time $end_date is set to. Not sure if that's a problem for the OP though. I assumed it was.

Comment: @vascowhite I'm guessing their `DateTime` objects were created using only the date portion ... if all else fails, there's still good old string compares =D

Comment: Could be. They have their answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do direct comparisons of DateTime objects, so something like this should work:-

```
/**
 * @param DateTime $start_date
 * @param DateTime $end_date
 * @return bool
 */
private function check_date_in_range(\DateTime $start_date, \DateTime $end_date)
{
    if ($start_date == null || $end_date == null) {
        //if either is null bail.
        return false;
    }
    $currDate = new \DateTime();
    $start_date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $end_date->setTime(23, 59, 59);

    // Check that current date is between start & end otherwise return FALSE.
    return ($start_date < $currDate && $currDate < $end_date);
}
```

You should realise too, that returning 1 can seem the same as returning true if you are using loose comparisons (==) in PHP.

Comment: Yeah, but what about leap seconds? ;-)

Comment: @Jack Ignore them, they'll go away :)